# What interpreters have been made using the PyPy Translator Toolchain?

Tags: interpreter, pypy, rpython

What interpreters have been made using the PyPy Translator Toolchain besides PyPy itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two most complete (besides the Python one) are Javascript and Prolog, but there are also Squeak, Scheme, Brainfuck, and Haskell in various levels of completeness.